# App stays in splash screen in iOS 7.0.3

Tags: ios, ios7, splash-screen

Recently in iOS 7.0.3, my app stays in the splash screen and was not going into the app at all.

If i kill the app and launch it again it opens up without any issues.

Can anyone help me on this issue?. I think the application `-didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` was not returning yes.

Note: I have a lot of stuffs like deleting database, initializing a dozen of buttons in appdelegate init function.

I know that it is a bad practice to have things in init but since its been there for more than 4 years and was working fine with previous OS versions i didn't find a good reason to change it.

Also this issue is not happening all the time.

My app size is 40 MB.

Answer (score 0):

The iOS Guidelines say that you should not include anything which holds the Splash screen for much time its better if you do all the process in background so that splash screens loads up and user can play with app. But as you said your issue is not all the time so Try to reset the app and also quit simulator. Hope this helps.